# Use of 'variation in' versus 'variation of'

Tags: word-choice

Are there rules for preferring the use of 'variation of' versus 'variation in'?

For example, in a sentence 'We found variation in the properties of the nerve cells' versus 'We found variation of the properties of the nerve cells'. Or in a title, 'Variation in the properties of nerve cells' versus 'Variation of the properties of nerve cells'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Variation of" is used to compare two things that doesn't necessarily mean the same thing.

"Cognac is a French variation of Brandy"

While "variation in" is talking about slight differences in the objects. Levels, amount and so on.

When you're referencing the properties of nerve cells, they become the object and as far as I can tell, you'd use

> We found variation in the properties of the nerve cells.